# Woocommerce checkout column total too small can not get it wider

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

On my site I have problems to get the total column wider.
I work with a child-theme. In the .css of it I declare this:

```
.woocommerce-checkout .checkout .shop_table .product-total {
 width: 30%;
}
```

or

```
.woocommerce-checkout .checkout .shop_table td:last-child {
 width: 30%;
}
```

Both are recognized. But did not help at all. See that there are more users fighting with the small total column. 
Does someone of you have a suggestion how to solve this via a child-theme?
Thanks for reading this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution from avada theme makers:
.checkout .shop_table tfoot th {
width: 85% !important;
}